# How to access methods/functions which are in a private data member of a class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Please take a look at the code sample.

1. A.dll will use class B in B.dll
2. b is a private member in class A

Now, there is a module C (C.dll or C.exe), C can access module A but can't access module B. But we want C could call methods of B, how could I adjust our design to approach that?

- we can't modify B.dll as it is a 3rd party module
- we can do some changes to class A, and we don't want to expose 2 methods in A to call B methods directly such as (which is not a good design, I think)

  `A::B_methods1() { b->B_methods1() }`

  `A::B_methods2() { b->B_methods2() }`
- and we also don't want to expose private data member b directly such as

  `const B* A::getB() { return b; }`

Any idea about it? thx a lot.

Add some comments:

it is very complicated (or need some special parameters) to build an instance of B. **We can only use A to build a B. so, if C want to access/call functions of B, C has to use through A.**

```
Module A.dll

class A
{
public:
    A ();
    virtual ~A();

private:
    B* b; 

}

Module B.dll

#ifdef SDK_DLL
#define HLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define HLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class HLAPI B
{
public:
    B ();
    virtual ~B();

public:
    B_method1();
    B_method2();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to call *private* B member functions outside of B?

Comment: @NikosC. Yes. a new module C, C want to access B functions. But C can't access module B, and can only access module A.

Comment: Then I suppose the `public:` specifier before B_method1() is a typo and you meant to write `private:`, right?

Comment: @NikosC. No. the methods of B are public. But to build an instance of B is very complicated, we can only  use A to create a B. so, if C want to access B, C can only use through A.

Comment: So the answer to my original comment should have been "no". You *don't* want to call private member functions of B. So a getter function will do. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you call methods of class A which directly call methods of its private member B it is not bad design, because B simply offers a kind of service and A uses it, but hides the usage. This also happens when you use a library which offers e.g. mail functionality - it is normal.

But, I would suggest to introduce an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) on the 3rd-party module B - this keeps it exchangeable, allows you to have more abstraction on B and let you also introduce some additional methods. 
Be careful with binding 3rd-party modules to your code using direct calls from "everywhere" - APIs change, which might cause a lot of maintenance work. But also keep in mind that you shouldn't encapsulate everything - especially not APIs with thousands of functions.

I know that these decisions are not easy, because they can cause a lot of work (or loss of time/money) in the end so keep your chin up ;-)
Btw. if you don't have them yet I can really recommend the books "Design patterns" (by Gamma et. al.), "Enterprise patterns" (by Fowler) and "Effective C++" (by Meyers).

*Jost

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the possibilities offered by the language

1. exposing the B member (not feasible, because of question constraints),
2. making C a friend o f A (I assume this is not feasible either, and I know this is hugly)
3. making B a protected member of A and privately deriving C from A
4. providing access functions, or other means for obtaining that A performs the desired operations on B (compound access functions, abstraction through facade/adaptor).

I would go for a mix of 1 and 4. I would isolate the B member of A into a "proxy" object with a facade/adaptor interface, then expose this object instead of exposing the B itself.

All of this would be bettere suited for your needs if you gave us some more details on the semantics of A, B and C.

Hope to have been of some help.